# printing max or min element from a list in python

Tags: python, list

[Output image of the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6T7v.png)I'm new to python and when I was printing max element from a list containing strings, I got the following output. Following is the code snippet:

```
list2 = ["hello","h","kgjfdxg","hhiudhshuhdxguh"]
print(min(list2))
print(max(list2))
```

Why it is printing max element as "kgjfdxg" when "hhiudhshuhdxguh" is largest element in list, or is it printing the max element with ASCII value of it?

Comment: Min and max are defined by alphabetical order, not length. If you want to use length as the condition, pass it in as the key: `min(list2, key=len)`

Answer (score 5):

think of min and max as like sorting then taking the first and last value. sorting strings they will be sorted alphabetically like words in a dictionary. If you want to print the min and max string by length then you need to tell max that the key to this sort is the len function

```py
list2 = ["hello","h","kgjfdxg","hhiudhshuhdxguh"]
print(min(list2, key=len))
print(max(list2, key=len))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `key` parameter:

```
list2 = ["hello","h","kgjfdxg","hhiudhshuhdxguh"]

print(min(list2, key=len))
print(max(list2, key=len))
```

This will yield

```
h
hhiudhshuhdxguh
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly does it sort it after the ABC format, in this case the first letter of each string is the one who is